# Asset Manager load pixmap outof mem Libgdx Java

Tags: java, android, libgdx, out-of-memory

I am creating a libgdx game, and it worked fine, loaded all of the assets perfectly etc. However I then tried to implement libgdx's `Asset Manager'`  to add an active loading screen etc. But after doing this my game would take ages to load on desktop, keeping a black screen, almost crashing then finally crash and on my assets I kept receiving the error or similar:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load 
    file: data/startBackground.png
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:130)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:121)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
        at com.MKgames.game1.screen.MainMenuScreen.show(MainMenuScreen.java:98)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
        at com.MKgames.Game1.render(Game1.java:41)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: couldn't load pixmap outofmem
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Gdx2DPixmap.<init>(Gdx2DPixmap.java:57)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:138)
        ... 10 more
```

I then tried deleting my assets class and the same thing keeps happening.

`data/startBackground.png`    is a 1920*1080 .png image.

I have a feeling it may be an issue more with the running it on the computer opposed to the game itself?

Here is how the asset is loaded normally without asset manager **(this used to work before i tried to implement asset manager but now it does not once i removed asset manager)**:

```
public void show() {
        Texture backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/startBackground.png"));
        background =  new Sprite (backgroundTexture);

}
```

Here's how I loaded this assets using asset manager:

```
public class Game1 extends Game{
public void render() {
        if(Assets.update()){
            this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
public class Assets {

    public static AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public static void queueLoading() {
        (..)
        manager.load("data/startBackground.png",Texture.class);
        (..)
    }
    public static boolean update() {
        return manager.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without you showing how you are actually loading the assets, it will be pretty difficult for us to help you. We need the code to it.

Comment: Please also note that an `AssetManager` should not be made static for mobile devices. This is covered [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#creating-an-assetmanager) under the bold text **Caution**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game1 render method is called every frame, so you are creating a new screen on each frame, and screen is creating a new texture instance in every show call, you finally get out of memory.

Also, don't forget to add

```
super.render();
```

In your game class render method. Otherwise, current screen's render() wont be called